# Slitherlink failure - help needed

Tags: grid-deduction, slitherlink

I have played "slitherlink" (or "Loopy" as it is sometimes called) generally on a 20x25 grid, so I don't finish too quickly.

However I have come across a puzzle (seed was not recorded), that MUST be solvable, but every attempt (2 dozen or so times) results in an impossibility.

Attached is a photo of the corner of the puzzle. The inconsistency happens while solving this corner, there has been no need to leave the bounds marked, before it fails. There are 2 zero squares, and a couple of 3-3 and 3-2-3 patterns to start from.

This failure is driving me crazy, and I have been very very cautious in checking each of my moves.

[image: slitherlink problem]

Comment: Shouldn't there be a grid deduction tag instead?

Comment: maybe this link can help: https://www.kakuro-online.com/slitherlink/

Comment: No need for 'grammar nazi' remarks in the edit history, please. The grammatical edit was made in good faith and improved the way the puzzle read. This site is run by all of its users, and the facility to edit another's question exists so that we can all benefit from constructive feedback like this. No need for name calling! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get any contradictions, but up to here was uniquely solvable (at least by my reasoning, if I didn't make a mistake) using the clues in the demarcated region. Hope this helps!

> [image: Partial solution]
>  *Click for higher-resolution image. I used [this site](http://pzv.jp/p.html?slither/12/14/gdhc2621bg12bgcg7bg2317cbg327c7bg3182dh811b70b73822111d366b66223dhddbg8ckc7162732572c37127cgd) to input the grid and draw my solution.*

Comment: 3-3's must contain the middle edge, otherwise you have a box.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry they also must contain the outermost edges, otherwise you have another invalid position. But I only made deductions in the indicated region from the question.

Comment: Okay I have found one point I was making a stupid mistake!  At this 3!

111
    1
    3   <---

Once I had that the rest came out exactly the same..
Simply point i was making a single mistake over and over again!

Thank you